# How to get a working UEFI / GRUB Boot - install process goes wrong

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have been experiencing great difficulty in simply getting pinguy ,mint or any of the other ubuntu based distros I have tried to complete the install process. I have read around the issue but the problem is that I am going around in circles.

I am pasting in the **[output from boot repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12762569/)** to see is anyone can spot where I am going wrong and possible offer a solution.

**All I want is a working UEFI /GRUB Boot.**

Comment: A title like "Where am I going wrong" is not informative. It doesn't tell anything about your problem. Please use a title that tells us about your problem. That will attract people with knowledge.

Comment: Tell us about the hardware. I've had big troubles getting Ubuntu work on a Lenovo laptop with UEFI. This can be very specific to your hardware. And let us know what you did, what you tried. As you've been trying to get this working for several days, you must have tried various options. If you let us know what, we don't have to waste our valuable time giving you solutions of which you already know that they don't work.

Comment: This site is for supporting the original Ubuntu and official variants, such as Xubuntu and Lubuntu. Mint doesn't qualify. I've never before heard of Pinguy, but I suspect it's also off-topic here. That said, if you try an official Ubuntu variant or post your question elsewhere, you need to be more specific about what's not working. Your Boot Repair output may be helpful, but without knowing what symptoms you're seeing, it's hard to offer advice. When does the installation fail? If it doesn't, what happens when you try to boot? If there are error messages, reproduce them *exactly.*

Comment: solved: it was the check box "secure boot"which was in boot repair .

Comment: solved: it was the check box "secure boot"which was in boot repair it was something I had not noticed before and I took the check off and it sort of installed. however having sorted that out, I am now trying to get the wifi sorted , same nonsense round and round. as for your comments " Ubuntu and official variants, such as Xubuntu and Lubuntu. Mint doesn't qualify. I've never before heard of Pinguy, " I've moved on and it looks as though it's back  to windows 8.1 as nothing works out of the box,  with my time being spent  chasing down busted threads and playing with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally. This solution helped me. The key is the sda1(in my case) in which efi boot resides. Have to check it in /etc/fstab in your linux distro:

**Identifying if an Ubuntu has been installed in UEFI mode**

An Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode can be detected the following way:
its /etc/fstab file contains an UEFI partition (mount point: /boot/efi)
it uses the grub-efi bootloader (not grub-pc)
from the installed Ubuntu, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then type the following command:

[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode"

If it shows: "installed in uefi mode" then you're home. Just few another steps.

Boot repair install:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

**Note**: Do not follow this procedure if your computer is already booting correctly. Use this procedure only if you believe you've accidentally installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and you want it to boot in UEFI/UEFI mode.

Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab.

1. If you do not see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, this means that your PC does not have any UEFI partition.

In this case, exit Boot-Repair, then create an UEFI partition (see the "Creating an UEFI partition" paragraph above).

2. **If you see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, tick it then click the "Apply" button.**

*Boot repair will ask to fire some commands during the installation. Fire them. Should go ok. If not perhaps wrong partition for grub is chosen.*

Also like it has been written in this post the uncheck box "secure boot" in "Grub Options" TAB

[Boot Repair UI view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK4mJ.png)

**Hope this helps in future threads. The key is to install /repair grub using this boot/efi separate partition. In other cases commands which boot-repair asks for don't work at all.**

Usefull resources

1. Comprehensive guide to UEFI idea 
   [Link 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting)